# Conditional presentation of Sale Price in Einstein Recommendations

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-recommendations

I am trying to set up conditional display of Sale Price, according to [these specs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_ampscript_functions_for_email_recommendations.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.dk%2F&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), in a following way:

```
%%[ if SalePriceMain > 0 then ]%%

  %%SalePrice%%

%%[ else ]%%

  %%RegularPrice%%

%%[ endif ]%%
```

The issue is, that I end up with showing the regular price, regardless if a positive sale price exists or not. I have displayed `%%SalePriceMain%%` and validated that it indeed holds an integer larger than 0. I have also used `&gt;` and `&lt;` instead of <> - also with no luck. The correct display shows up briefly in the preview, but within a second the example defaults back to the regular price only option.
 
Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: This is not an answer but rather an advice. Email Recommendations are really bad implemented. I would not use them at all. Create a WebRecommendation Call, perform it with httpget inside the newsletter [requires Supermessages like you told me]. Parse the json / html which is coming back, perform ampscript logic to get the variables. Display the variables like you want them to be. This may include the layout to be inside the ampscript code. It may need to have its own logic because the recommendation call might give you varying numbers of items. Cheers Mate.

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach will be the inability for the recommendations to adjust post send-time. If you are using email recommendations, they will update once every X hours (can't remember X). So if a product is sold out between send time and you opening the email, it will not be recommended.

Comment: the system default fields "Sale price" and "Regular Price" are INT fields, all other fields in the catalog are VARCHAR fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of my usage of SalePriceMain, rather than SalePrice. Even though, according to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_ampscript_functions_for_email_recommendations.htm), the SalePriceMain should be the variable to reference (when one wants to use a numerical value of the price field), I never managed to make it work. Once I switched to using SalePrice, I managed to make it work:

```
%%[ if SalePrice > 0 then ]%%
  %%SalePrice%%
%%[ else ]%%
  %%RegularPrice%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Shout out to [EazyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I tested it (not with Price because i dont have it available). The problem might have been your "0" like shown later. And in the AMPScript you need to use `> <` and not the encoded html stuff.

Have not looked into side effects though. -> Can be a false positive. Because > in Strings can just mean length or whatever. But hadn't had the time to test properly.

**Works for me:**

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%[ if Category > ProductType then ]%%
<span style="color:red;">Sale Price: %%Category%%</span>
%%[ else ]%%
%%ProductType%%
%%[ endif ]%%
</div>
```

**Does not work for me:**

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%[ if Category > 0 then ]%%
Category: %%Category%%<br>
<span style="color:red;">Sale Price: %%Category%%</span>
%%[ else ]%%
%%ProductType%%
%%[ endif ]%%
</div>
```

*Conclusion -> 0 might be your problem.*

**Changed 0 to "0". Works for me.**

```
<div style="font-size:12px;color:black;width:150px; text-align:center;">
<img style="max-width:150px;" src="%%ImageLink%%">
<p>%%ProductName%%</p>
%%[ if Category > "0" then ]%%
Category: %%Category%%<br>
<span style="color:red;">Sale Price: %%Category%%</span>
%%[ else ]%%
%%ProductType%%
%%[ endif ]%%
</div>
```